# gulp-plumber throws error then stops build.

Tags: javascript, gulp

Having an issue with `gulp-plumber` as it breaks my build upon a error throw.

For example I make a change to my `scss` with an invalid syntax such as `padding-left:woah-err`. Plumber notifies me in the terminal of the error. Then I got back to `scss` file make the change to `padding-left:20px;` save and get **no response** in terminal and it looks like my gulp build is broken...To fix I haft to restart gulp.

However inside my gulp file if I change `this.emit('end');` to `this.emit();` the build dose not break but I get no plumber notifications of errors anymore.

Looking into changing up the way my I configured my plumber to get this to work right. Any suggestions? This looks like a [good solution](https://github.com/floatdrop/gulp-plumber/issues/38#issuecomment-140677501).

Here's my packages

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
 fs = require('fs'),
 gulpif = require('gulp-if'), // condtionally run task
 plumber = require('gulp-plumber'), // prevent pipe breaking
 browserSync = require('browser-sync').create(),
 bower = require('gulp-bower'), // gulp bower
 concat = require('gulp-concat'), // concat files
 cssmin = require('gulp-minify-css'), // minify css
 rename = require('gulp-rename'), // rename file
 runSequence = require('run-sequence'), // runs gulp tasks in order
 sass = require('gulp-sass'), // css preprocessor
 uglify = require('gulp-uglify'); // minify js
```

Here's my styles task (had someone help me set this up)..Might want to rethink it's structure. Open to suggestions

```
// Styles Task
gulp.task('styles', function(){
    // streamError is set to false
    var streamError = false;
    return gulp.src(paths.source.styles)
        .pipe(plumber({
            // plumber finds errors in stream
            errorHandeler:function(error){
                streamError = error;
                // plumber logs errors to console and terminal
                console.log(streamError.message);
                browserSync.notify(streamError.message,errorTimeout);
                this.emit('end');
            }
        }))
        .pipe(sass())
         // compile sass
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.destination.styles))
        // if the streamError is NOT false reload browser
        .pipe(gulpif(!streamError,browserSync.reload({stream:true})))
        .pipe(cssmin()) // min css
        .pipe(rename({ // rename file to site.min.css
            suffix:'.min'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.destination.styles))
        // if streamError is not `false` reload browser
        .pipe(gulpif(!streamError,browserSync.reload({stream:true})));
});
```

Here's the error
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This fixed the problem for me.

`Using gulp-plumber 1.1.0`

```
function onError(err) {
    console.log(err); //or other way you may prefer to log
    this.emit('end');
}

gulp.task('myTask', function(){
    return gulp
    .src('myFilePath')
    .pipe(plumber(onError))
    [...]
}
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

I think because when error happens, Gulp didnt receive the finished callback;
You may need add a done param to your task function.
if there is error, you will call done() manually.
Simple:

```
// Styles Task
gulp.task('styles', function( done /** done! **/){
    // streamError is set to false
    var streamError = false;
    return gulp.src(paths.source.styles)
        .pipe(plumber({
            // plumber finds errors in stream
            errorHandeler:function(error){
                streamError = error;
                // plumber logs errors to console and terminal
                console.log(streamError.message);
                browserSync.notify(streamError.message,errorTimeout);
                this.emit('end');
                done();//call done here!
            }
        }))
        //keep the same.....
});
```

hope it's help